# Find file with certain extension and calculate its hash in Java

Tags: java, hash, md5, file-extension

I want to calculate the MD5 hash of a file that ends with a certain extension in Java. I used two codes for this:

FileSearch.java

```
public class FileSearch
{
    public static File findfile(File file) throws IOException
    {
        String drive = (new DetectDrive()).USBDetect();

        Path start = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(drive);
        Files.walkFileTree(start, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
            @Override
            public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
            {
                if (file.toString().endsWith(".raw"))
                {
                    System.out.println(file);
                }
                return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
            }
        });
        return file;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        Hash hasher = new Hash();
        try
        {
            if (file.toString().endsWith("raw"))
            {
                hasher.hash(file);
            }
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Hash.java

```
public class Hash
{
    public void hash(File file) throws Exception 
    {
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);

        byte[] dataBytes = new byte[1024];

        int nread = 0;
        while ((nread = fis.read(dataBytes)) != -1) 
        {
            md.update(dataBytes, 0, nread);
        };

        byte[] mdbytes = md.digest();
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i = 0; i < mdbytes.length; i++) 
        {
            sb.append(Integer.toString((mdbytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
        }

        System.out.println("Digest(in hex format):: " + sb.toString());
    }
}
```

The first code is used to search for the file that ends with .raw while the second code (not completed yet) is used to get the raw file and then calculate its hash. However, I do not know how to call the first code into the second code to get that raw file. I believe I have to put a string inside the new FileInputStream(...) but I need to call the raw file instead.

Is it possible to do so since both of them contain a main method? Or do I need to change the FileSearch.java without the main method and have a "public String search()" instead and then call it in the second code? I would appreciate if you could show me how to do it the right way.

Answer (score 0):

So the logic consists in these steps:

```
for each file with the .raw extension
    hash the file
```

You should thus have a method `void hash(File file)`, and call it from your first class.

So, in Hash.java, rename your main method to

```
public void hash(File file)
```

And open the file using

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Then call this hash() method from your first class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    Hash hasher = new Hash();
    ...
            if (file.toString().endsWith(".raw")) {
                hasher.hash(file);
            }
    ...
}
```

You'll also have to make sure that every FileInputStream you create is properly closed, otherwise you'll quickly run out of file descriptors. The best way to do that is to use the try-with-resources construct: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I have a question regarding the "..." portion. Is there anything else that I should include for that part other than the try-with-resources?

Comment: I have edited the codes from what I understand from your explanation. Did I use the 'try' portion correctly? The program is not able to read the "file" under the main method. I believe I am missing something but I don't know what it is. I would appreciate any explanation. Thanks!